# deprecation warning in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie to Rails and programming in general (currently learning from a book that's using 3.0.1 and ruby 1.9.2).

When I did the rake db:migrate command I got the following deprecation warning. I'm not sure if this is because I'm using a slightly older version of Rails, or if it would happen no matter what the version. Anyways, can anyone tell me what if anything I'm supposed to do now?

As I am a newbie a detailed answer would be very appreciated. Cheers

```
$ rake db:migrate


WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method SampleApp::Application#task called at /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
```

**Update with rakefile**

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

SampleApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: Could you please show your rakefile?

Comment: I've updated the OP with my rake file. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Rake 0.9.x, you have two options:

1. Upgrade to at least rails 3.0.8 (which fixes integration with Rake 0.9.x, as stated [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/6/8/ann-rails-3-0-8-has-been-released)). This can be achieved by changing your gem file to `gem rails, '3.0.8'` (or higher) and running `bundle install`.
2. You could probably downgrade to Rake 0.8.x to fix this warning, but I highly recommend the first option.

Comment: o.k. thanks, i'm only using rails 3.0.1 to follow along with this book. I will upgrade later